# Facebook API for retrieving Group membership requests

Tags: facebook-graph-api, group-membership

I am looking for an API to call facebook to get List of Group membership request.

Currently I am using following Graph API with OAuth :

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/177043492441355/members?fields=email,id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,name,gender,is_verified,cover

It is returning available members details, not a group member request list.

Is there a way to get the list of group member request with email Ids?

Your reply will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Binumon

Comment: Did you findanything?

Answer (score 0):

Use this metrix /group_id/member_requests